# How to open custom files in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that i want to open my custom file (.CMF). I have these files in a folder and i want to make it that if someone types the number 1, that it will display the text that is inside that .cmf file. i remember it being something like >C:\blahblah. ANY HElp

I tried:

```
echo >C:\CMFfiles\ThankYou
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `type`, as in `type myfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:loop
SET "file="
SET /p file="Which file to show ? "
IF NOT DEFINED file ECHO Goodbye&GOTO :EOF
IF NOT EXIST "%file%.cmf" ECHO %file% seems to be missing&GOTO loop
CLS
ECHO TYPE "%file%.cmf"
TYPE "%file%.cmf"
ECHO ======== This is %file% ===========
GOTO loop
```

This should work for you.

Get a name from the user - terminate if nothing is entered.
check that the file exists if not, say so and ask again, otherwise clear the screen, type the file, report the name entered and ask for another file.